# Confusing Error message when using Brew

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, command-line, homebrew

Every time when I run a brew command, it will give me several error lines at the beginning. I can't understand what's going on here. Can anyone tell me how I can get rid of the error?

```
brew
/bin/sh: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: ` ruby-+([1-9]) | ruby-+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | ruby-1.+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | jruby-[19]*)'
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_ruby_string_find'
/bin/sh: __rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file: line 9: ` __rvm_read_lines __variables <( { cat "$1"; echo ""; } | __rvm_sed "${__sed_commands[@]}" )'
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file'
/bin/sh: __rvm_remove_without_gems: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_remove_without_gems: line 2: ` __rvm_read_lines __gems_to_remove <('
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_remove_without_gems'
```

Now I found if I run an illegal command for ruby, it gives me a same error message. So is it because my version problem?
[image]

Comment: So, `brew` doesn't work at all, just showing these errors?

Comment: @ForceBru It seems like brew works well, but I am not sure weather this error message would hurt the functionalities.

Comment: why don't you try it then?

Comment: @ForceBru I just ran command "Ruby", it looks like the problem is comes from ruby. But I do install ruby." ruby --version
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]"

Comment: you can (re)install Ruby as said in my answer

Comment: @ForceBru Hi, you could see my update for this question, it seems like it is because the illegal command inside brew.  Is it because I use the wrong version of ruby for brew in my computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78232/discussion-between-haoyu-chen-and-forcebru).

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, you need to install [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) first as the errors you're receiving are coming from BASH (it is trying to parse the script as bash but doesn't succeed). Not sure how you managed to install Homebrew without ruby.

Comment: I still can't figure out that issue -- but I do install ruby again and again. It doesn't solve the problem. Ruby I installted is newest version

Comment: @HaoyuChen, can you run a simple ruby script from console, or does it give the same errors?

Comment: Oh, I tried it and it can run 'puts "hello world"' . And it doesn't give any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error due to RVM being source'ed during bash profile setup.
It seems the RVM script cannot handle being sourced multiple times into the same shell.

This was being triggered by commands like `ssh-agent`, which spawn a new sub-shell, or simply running `bash` again.

My solution was to wrap the RVM source'ing in my `.bashrc` with a check for the `$rvm_version` variable:

```
if [ -z "$rvm_version" ]; then
    export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
fi
```